# Selecionar maior valor PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte:

```
$gols = array("Kraken"=>"25",        "Cleiton.Xavier"=>"10",     "Buffon"=>"0",
```

Eu queria achar o maior valor de `$gols` e o nome do jogador também como faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`arsort`](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.asort.php) do PHP para ordenar o *array* `$gols` e dessa forma buscar o primeiro valor dele, que será o maior. Tente assim:

```
$gols = [
    "Kraken" => "25"
    "Cleiton.Xavier" => "10",
    "Buffon" => "50"
];

arsort($gols);
var_dump($gols);
```

Retorna:

> array(3) { ["Buffon"]=> string(2) "50" ["Kraken"]=> string(2) "25" ["Cleiton.Xavier"]=> string(2) "10" }

Agora você tem no primeiro índice do array a pessoa com o maior número de gols.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função `max()` que retornar o maior valor e `array_search()` para procurar no array o nome de quem possui esse número de gols.

*Exemplo:*

```
$gols = array("Kraken"=>"25",        "Cleiton.Xavier"=>"10",     "Buffon"=>"50");

$maiorGol  = max($gols); *//Retorna 50*
$maiorNome = array_search ($maiorGol,$gols); *//Retorna Buffon*
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu estava precisando.

Comment: Por nada, Thiago!

Comment: acerta esse comentário aí

Answer (score 0):

Para retornar maior valor -> função `max()`

```
$gols = array("Pequnion"=>"25","Minimion"=>"10","Zeron"=>"0","Grandon"=>"100","Medion"=>"50");

echo max($gols);

$maxs = array_keys($gols, max($gols));

echo ($maxs[0]);
```

> ```
> Para retornar a chave do maior valor, uso array_keys
> pois pode haver vários valores máximos iguais
> ```
>
> [**Exemplo no ideone com dois valores máximos iguais**](https://ideone.com/yNZ4C6)

[**array_keys**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) - as chaves das posições onde determinado valor se encontra.

> exemplo:

```
$arr = array("determinado valor", "um valor", "outro valor", "determinado valor", "determinado valor");
var_dump(array_keys($arr, "determinado valor));
```

> retorna

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(4)
}
```

> Porque "`determinado valor`" está presente nas posições 0, 3 e 4 do array.